# While loop, statement for every other loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop and each one displays a `<li></li>` in a list, is there a way to tell php that every other loop should echo say:

```
<li style="background: #222;"></li>
```

and in my css I would have another colour #111 set as default so users of my site can easily determine which row of data they are seeing?

my code as requested:

```
function user_details($dbc, $q, $details) {
echo '<ul class="userlist">';
while ($user = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo '<li><span>(' . $user['id'] . ')</span> <a href="/viewaccount?id=' . $user['id'] . '">' . $user['username'] . '</a><div>';

    if ($user['admin'] > 0) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/admin.png" width="18" height="18" title="Is game admin." alt="" />';
    }

    echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/' . $user['gender'] . '.png" width="18" height="18" title="' . $user['gender'] . '" alt="" />';

    $last_active = time() - $user['last_active'];
    $seconds = $last_active % 60;
        $minutes = ($last_active - $seconds) / 60;
    if ($minutes <= 4) {
    echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/active5.png" width="18" height="18" alt="" title="';
        if ($seconds == 0) {
            echo 'Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes ago." />';
        }
        elseif ($minutes == 0) {
            echo 'Last active ' . $seconds . ' seconds ago." />';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes and ' . $seconds . ' seconds ago." />';
        }
    }
    elseif ($minutes <= 9) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/active10.png" width="18" height="18" alt="" title="';
        if ($seconds == 0) {
            echo '<strong>Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes ago." />';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes and ' . $seconds . ' seconds ago." />';
        }
    }
    elseif ($minutes <= 14) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/active15.png" width="18" height="18" alt="" title="';
        if ($seconds == 0) {
            echo 'Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes ago." />';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Last active ' . $minutes . ' minutes and ' . $seconds . ' seconds ago." />';
        }
    }

    if ($user['subscriber'] > 0) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/subscriber.png" width="18" height="18" title="Subscriber with ' . $user['subscriber'] . ' days left." alt="" />';
    }

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<a href="#"><img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/sendmessage.png" width="18" height="18" title="Send ' . $user['username'] . ' a message." alt="" /></a>';

    $is_friend = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT id, friend_id FROM friends WHERE id = ? && friend_id = ?");
    $is_friend -> execute(array($details['id'], $user['id']));
    $friend_request = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT id, id_to FROM friend_requests WHERE id = ? || id_to = ? && id = ? || id_to = ?");
    $friend_request -> execute(array($user['id'], $details['id'], $details['id'], $user['id']));
    if ($is_friend -> rowCount() > 0) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/isfriend.png" width="18" height="18" title="Friend request sent to ' . $user['username'] . '." alt="" />';
    }
    elseif ($friend_request -> rowCount() > 0) {
        echo '<img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/friendrequested.png" width="18" height="18" title="There is a request pending to be friends with ' . $user['username'] . '." alt="" />';
    }
    else {
        echo '<a href="/confirm?action=addfriend&amp;id=' . $user['id'] . '"><img class="Tooltip" src="gameimages/addfriend.png" width="18" height="18" title="Add ' . $user['username'] . ' as a friend." alt="" /></a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
 }
```

It is in a function at the min, basically each other row should have another background :)

Comment: I have read this twice - what exactly is the question?

Comment: Could you show us your while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an boolean flag to keep track is it odd or even row, ie

```
$isOdd = true;
while(...){
  if($isOdd) echo '<li style="background: #222;"></li>';
  else echo '<li></li>';
  $isOdd = ! $isOdd;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks alot :) could you please explain your answer to what is actually happen here so I can learn this technique if you have the time, thanks :)

Comment: Well, it's really simple - the `$isOdd` is an boolean variable initialized to `true` and in the end of the loop you switch it's value between `true` and `false` (the `$isOdd = ! $isOdd;` statement, it reads `$isOdd = not $isOdd` ie it cycles between true and false).

Answer (score 3):

You want all even values to display something else; this will do that using the modulo operator:

```
$index = 0;
while($user = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   if(++$index%2 == 0) //is index +1 even?
     echo '<li style="background: #222;"></li>';
   else
     echo '<li></li>';
}
```

If possible, you could change to a for loop since you'd have your `$index` already defined.

Answer (score 3):

Or better still

```
$isOdd = true;
while(...){
  echo '<li class="' . ($isodd ? 'odd' : 'even'). '"></li>
  $isOdd = ! $isOdd;
}
```

Then put the colors into the style sheet - it has the advantage you can even change the fonts etc. You can even give it a fresh look without needing to change the code

Comment: Very nice :) didn't think of this ;)

Comment: If you are clever- have a CSS in the pocket - you can get a rise in 6 ths

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
$colors = array('111', '222');
$i = 0;
while (...) {
    echo '<li style="background: #' . $colors[$i % count($colors)] . '"></li>';
    $i++;
}
```

For neatness you could also turn your `while` loop into a `for` loop. For example:

```
$colors = array('111', '222');
for ($i = 0; ...; $i++) {
    echo '<li style="background: #' . $colors[$i % count($colors)] . '"></li>';
}
```

Comment: why are you counting your array's content on each loop ? PHP is not threaded, so your array won't be updated during the loop's execution, until you add data in it from the loop. If your array is huge, this will hurt...