# Use PHP to display every nth row from mysqli_fetch_array while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Many others have asked something similar but I haven't been able to correctly apply any guidance/answers to my issue.

Original PHP loop for all records that works:

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

        $date = $row['date'];
        $o_name = $row['o_name'];
        $g_name = $row['g_name'];
        echo    "<tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$o_name</td>
                <td>$g_name</td>
                </tr>\n";
        }
```

Failed attempts at displaying only every nth record (2nd, in this case):

A:

```
        $x=0
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

        $date = $row[$x]['date'];
        $o_name = $row[$x]['o_name'];
        $g_name = $row[$x]['g_name'];
        $x = $x + 2;
        echo    "<tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$o_name</td>
                <td>$g_name</td>
                </tr>\n";
        }
```

B:

```
        $x=0
        while($row[$x]=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

        $date = $row['date'];
        $o_name = $row['o_name'];
        $g_name = $row['g_name'];
        $x = $x + 2;
        echo    "<tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$o_name</td>
                <td>$g_name</td>
                </tr>\n";
        }
```

C:

```
        $x=0
        while($row[$x]=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

        $date = $row[$x}['date'];
        $o_name = $row[$x}['o_name'];
        $g_name = $row[$x}['g_name'];
        $x = $x + 2;
        echo    "<tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$o_name</td>
                <td>$g_name</td>
                </tr>\n";
        }
```

I feel like I'm in the ballpark and in the correct section but just can't find my seat.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code perhaps - seeing the SQL might help. Try dumping our the var which holds the SQL and check it, and run the dumped SQL in the DB manually to eliminate potential issues

Comment: This question has indeed been asked before. Have a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359972/401980) which I think may be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks James and Benji.  One of the answers in that question from 2011 showed the IF statement I was missing and where to insert it into the loop (in addition to moving my incremented counter down after the echo).  Seems to be working now after a few quick tests.  I'll continue playing with it.  Much appreciated!

Comment: you want to print only last row of the result. is that correct?